# Generating a date in a particular timezone

Tags: javascript

I have a timezone string, for example, "Pacific Time (US & Canada)". I need to get the equivalent of 3pm in that timezone in UTC for particular dates, including daylight savings time. How can I go about this?

For example, I need to find 3pm on December 3rd, PDT in UTC time.

Comment: Does _Date_ recognise the timezone? e.g. for me `new Date('2013-10-15 00:25:00 PST').toUTCString(); // "Tue, 15 Oct 2013 08:25:00 GMT"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That time zone identifier looks like it came from Rails, or from Twitter (which uses Rails).  You first need to convert it to a standard IANA zone identifer such as "America/Los_Angeles".  See the `MAPPING` declaration in the [ActiveSupport::TimeZone docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).

Then you can use one of the libraries I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

In particular, you may want to try [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).  You'll need the latest develop version for this particular feature, as it was added in issue [#25](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/25) which is not yet in the current release.  Then you can do something like this:

```
moment.tz("2013-12-03T15:00:00","America/Los_Angeles").utc().format()
```

You can adjust the input/output format to whatever makes sense for you and is supported by [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

The other time zone libraries [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824) may also offer similar features without as much overhead, so they are worth a look.

Comment: @DanPalumbo - Updated to give you some code to start with.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me though it does feel a little fragile

```
new Date('2013-12-03 15:00:00 PDT').toUTCString()

    -> "Tue, 03 Dec 2013 22:00:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Only a small handful of timezone abbreviations are recognized by this method.  See [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) section 5.1.  In general, time zone abbreviations are not useful because there is too much ambiguity.  For example, is "CST" short for "Central Standard Time" or "China Standard Time"?

Comment: This will work, though it would be nice if I could do it from the full fledged timezone string and not the abbreviation.

Comment: @MattJohnson Another option is to replace the abbreviation with the offset in `±hhmm` format e.g. `-0700` or `-0800`.

Comment: @PaulS. - Absolutely.  If you know the offset already, then half the battle is over and there is no need for the actual timezone in either abbreviated or IANA form.  What you can't do is start replacing abbreviations with specific offsets.  There are just too many overlaps and conflicts.

Comment: See [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations) for a better idea of all of the possible time zone abbreviations.