# UTC to CST Conversion using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert the start date of an event in UTC time to America/Chicago time using moment.js

The given input of the start date is '2021-02-10T03:05:00Z'.

I am trying to convert that input to a start time of '2012-02-09' at 9:00PM CST.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a date in a particular timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370849/generating-a-date-in-a-particular-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the timeZone like this

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment('2021-02-10T03:05:00Z').tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('LL');
```

The timeZone isn't the one you are looking for, to get a list of the timeZone names you need to call `moment.tz.zonesForCountry('US');`

It should get you a list of all the timezones for your country then you just have to pick the right one for Chicago, and then you can format it like you want it displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! so i did this

`moment('2021-02-10T03:05:00Z').tz("America/Chicago").format()`

and it gave me 

`2021-02-10T03:05:00-06:00` 

was hoping it would give me this date 2012-02-09 with 9pm

Comment: Did you import `moment-timezone` instead of `moment` ?

Comment: Yep, required moment-timezone instead of moment and did `moment('2021-02-10T03:05:00Z').tz("America/Chicago").format('LL')` and it yields `February 10, 2021`

Comment: Maybe try it like this => `moment.tz('2021-02-10T03:05:00Z', "America/Chicago").format('LLLL')` both ways work on my side, I'll correct my answer if that way works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `moment-timezone` for this. Here is the working code example.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<div id="utc-time">09/02/2021 12:40:35 PM</div>
<div id="cst-time"></div>
<div id="aus-time"></div>

var dt = document.getElementById("utc-time").innerHTML;  
var m = moment.utc(dt, "DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A"); // parse input as UTC
console.log(m.clone().local().format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A")); // local time
document.getElementById("utc-time").innerHTML = m.clone().local().format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A (Z)");
var tz = 'America/New_York'; // timezone value, you can use moment.tz.guess() for automatic detection
document.getElementById("cst-time").innerHTML = m.clone().tz(tz).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A (Z)");
tz = 'Australia/Perth'; // test another timezone
document.getElementById("aus-time").innerHTML = m.clone().tz(tz).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss A (Z)");
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9c2f068z/